# Assign an ID based on multiple criteria

Tags: r

I am new to R and am trying to put together a script to automate a now very manual task of triangulating different reports.

In my job I receive reports from different sources, which I need to triangulate and aggregate if needed. To simplify (and anonymise) my example let's say that I get reports about sales made by different merchants in a market. This data includes "Observer", "Seller", "Buyer", and "Date of sale".

Example:

```
market <- data.frame(observer=c("Tom", "Fred", "Hank", "Tom"), 
seller=c("A", "A", "B", "A"),
buyer=c("X", "X", "Y", "X"),
date_sale=c("2017/01/01", "2017/01/03", "2017/01/04", "2017/01/05"))
```

Now, some of this data might overlap, so I need to make sure that I know if a transaction has been reported already across merchants in a similar time period (+/- 7 days) and assign the same ID to it (so later I can merge the two). If, however, the same observer reports the same transaction again a short time later I can assume that in that case it's a separate one.

In my example, I can see that Tom and Fred both reported a purchase from A to X within 2 days of each other, while Tom reported a second one in the same time period. So ideally R should give the same ID to the first two transactions and a separate one to the third.

The result should be:

```
market <- data.frame(observer=c("Tom", "Fred", "Hank", "Tom"), 
seller=c("A", "A", "B", "A"),
buyer=c("X", "X", "Y", "X"),
date_sale=c("2017/01/01", "2017/01/03", "2017/01/04", "2017/01/05"),
id=c(1, 1, 2, 3))
```

I have tried with `getanID` from the `splitstackshape` package, but I cannot manage to find out how to give a parameter of "within +/- 7 days of an earlier transaction". I am open to any suggestions, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm a little unclear about your criteria. Shouldn't Tom's second transaction also have an id of 1 because it was within 7 days of the first one? (Nevermind, I see a sentence about this being a special case.)

Comment: Yes indeed, in that case I can assume that it's a second transaction rather than a duplicate of the first one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness sake, I added another data point to your data.frame, that is more than 7 days away. I also converted your dates to the correct class to simplify date arithmetic:

```
market <- data.frame(observer=c("Tom", "Fred", "Hank", "Tom", "Joe"),
                 seller=c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
                 buyer=c("X", "X", "Y", "X", "X"),
                 date_sale=as.Date(c("2017/01/01", "2017/01/03",
                        "2017/01/04","2017/01/05", "2017/01/09")) )
```

The first step you'll want to do is bin your data into 7-day bins:

```
library( dplyr )    # We'll make extensive use of this package
m1 <- market %>% mutate( date_bin = as.integer((date_sale - min(date_sale)) / 7) )
#   observer seller buyer  date_sale date_bin
# 1      Tom      A     X 2017-01-01        0
# 2     Fred      A     X 2017-01-03        0
# 3     Hank      B     Y 2017-01-04        0
# 4      Tom      A     X 2017-01-05        0
# 5      Joe      A     X 2017-01-09        1
```

The final id is going to be a product of two "sub-IDs": the outer ID which comes from grouping your data by `date_bin`, `seller` and `buyer` (i.e., what are all the possible versions of transactions that can happen within a 7-day period), and the inner ID which enumerates duplicate transactions made by the same observer **within** each group.

The two IDs can be computed as follows:

```
i1 <- m1 %>% group_by( date_bin, seller, buyer ) %>% group_indices()
m2 <- m1 %>% mutate( outID = i1 ) %>% group_by( outID, observer ) %>%
        mutate( inID = 1:n() )
#   observer seller buyer  date_sale date_bin outID inID
# 1      Tom      A     X 2017-01-01        0     1    1
# 2     Fred      A     X 2017-01-03        0     1    1
# 3     Hank      B     Y 2017-01-04        0     2    1
# 4      Tom      A     X 2017-01-05        0     1    2
# 5      Joe      A     X 2017-01-09        1     3    1
```

Finally, we create the final id from all the unique pairs of `outID` and `inID`:

```
market %>% mutate( id = group_by( m2, outID, inID ) %>% group_indices() )
#   observer seller buyer  date_sale id
# 1      Tom      A     X 2017-01-01  1
# 2     Fred      A     X 2017-01-03  1
# 3     Hank      B     Y 2017-01-04  3
# 4      Tom      A     X 2017-01-05  2
# 5      Joe      A     X 2017-01-09  4
```

Note that the indices are not exactly in the same order as what you requested in your question, but since these are arbitrary integers, you can reassign them to desired values without loss of generality.

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks great. My only worry with creating 7 day bins relates to observations that might be repeated at the "margins" of the two groups. E.g.: what if the same transaction is observed on 2017-01-05 and on 2017-01-09? In that case they would fall into different bins, but would still need to be triangulated because they are less than 7 days apart.

Comment: Is that a well-constrained task? In your example, how do you know that the transaction Fred observed is the same as Tom's first transaction, not Tom's second one? 2017-01-03 is equidistant to 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-05.

Comment: Another example: suppose Tom observes two transactions, one at 2017-01-01 and one at 2017-01-07. Fred also observes two transactions, one at 2017-01-06 and another at 2017-01-11. All transactions are the same buyer-seller pair. How do you triangulate this? Is this two total transactions, observed by both Tom and Fred; or is this three total transactions with Tom's 2017-01-07 and Fred's 2017-01-06 being the same one?

Comment: That is a very good question! Welcome to my world. I think that the best solution would be to take the first transaction as reference and triangulate the second one from another observer within 7 days, ie. assume that Fred's observation on 2017-01-06 is Tom's from 2017-01-01, and so on for the second one. That being said, I realise that this is not a greatly reliable system. I think that some manual supervision will still be necessary to further reduce possible duplication but creating 7 day bins could save me some time. Thank you again, I will try this and see how it goes!

Comment: If you're always triangulating to the earlier date, you can think about picking a "reference" observer, and binning all data around their observations. For example, if Tom is the reference, Bin 1 is between Tom's first and second transaction, Bin 2 is between Tom's second and third, and so on. (I would pick an observer with the largest number of transactions, to ensure that the bins are 7 days of smaller). After that, your IDs are just `market %>% group_by( bin, buyer, seller ) %>% group_indices()` (i.e., all unique transactions in each bin).